Error when append data to Iceberg using Spark
I read a csv file in MinIO Bucket and tried to append it to Iceberg table but error occurred.
This is my code:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Initialize SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MinIO to Iceberg") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.2,org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.12:1.4.1,org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-aws-bundle:1.4.1") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "http://localhost:9000") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "admin") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "password") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "false") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.demo", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.demo.type", "rest") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.demo.uri", "http://localhost:8181") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.demo.io-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.demo.warehouse", "s3://warehouse") \
    .getOrCreate()
    
# Read CSV file from MinIO
csv_file_path = "s3a://mybucket/raw/customers-100.csv"

df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(csv_file_path)

df.show()

df.write.format("iceberg").mode("append").save("demo.dwh.user2")

# Stop the SparkSession
spark.stop()

**ERROR**
ERROR Utils: Aborting task (0 + 1) / 1] software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint. (Service: S3, Status Code: 301, Request ID: RGZR9VQCQCKK0PS8, Extended Request ID: AfwIofUYlix/iPHXuzNMr53PadSpvc1w1WHoGOZBsrN5FA54MeXuCa2g2z0dmBKREFFAHpPRfeY=)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handleErrorResponse(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:156)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handleResponse(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:108)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handle(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:85)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handle(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:43)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler$Crc32ValidationResponseHandler.handle(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:95)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseClientHandler.lambda$successTransformationResponseHandler$7(BaseClientHandler.java:270)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:40)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:30)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:72)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:78)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:40)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:52)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:37)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:81)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:56)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:50)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:32)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:196)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:103)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:171)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:82)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:179)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:76)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:45)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:56)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.putObject(DefaultS3Client.java:8783)
    at org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3OutputStream.completeUploads(S3OutputStream.java:438)
    at org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3OutputStream.close(S3OutputStream.java:265)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.parquet.io.DelegatingPositionOutputStream.close(DelegatingPositionOutputStream.java:38)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.end(ParquetFileWriter.java:1204)
    at org.apache.iceberg.parquet.ParquetWriter.close(ParquetWriter.java:257)
    at org.apache.iceberg.io.DataWriter.close(DataWriter.java:82)
    at org.apache.iceberg.io.RollingFileWriter.closeCurrentWriter(RollingFileWriter.java:122)
    at org.apache.iceberg.io.RollingFileWriter.close(RollingFileWriter.java:147)
    at org.apache.iceberg.io.RollingDataWriter.close(RollingDataWriter.java:32)
    at org.apache.iceberg.spark.source.SparkWrite$UnpartitionedDataWriter.close(SparkWrite.java:737)
    at org.apache.iceberg.spark.source.SparkWrite$UnpartitionedDataWriter.commit(SparkWrite.java:719)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WritingSparkTask.$anonfun$run$1(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1397)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WritingSparkTask.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:486)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WritingSparkTask.run$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:425)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:491)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

I tried connect iceberg to nessie and change uri to http://nessie:19120/nessie/main but I can't found my table.

whenever the AWS error message includes an extended request ID -assume it has come from Amazon s3, not a third party one.
that stack implies you are using iceberg's own S3 connector, not the hadoop s3a one -the one which picked up all fs.s3a values you used to (correctly) connect to a local store.
You'll need to look at the iceberg documentation to see what the equivalents are for: endpoint, path style access, maybe http rather than https
